# Change some account settings when new e-mail received

Tags: php, email, google-apps-script, gmail

I need to change one setting in my account on a web site each time when I receive email from the given address with a given text.
As I understand it should not be a big problem with Google Apps Scripts.
I see it so:
1) Each time, when I receive email (gmail account) script checks the sender and whether it contains necessary text.
2) If so, than I call PHP script which logs in the site and changes the necessary setting (HTTPResponse ?).
I found few examples how to log in and post data with PHP, so I could create PHP script to do this and use some hosting for it. This file will be than called from google scripts.

Is it possible to implement this task in this way?
Can I do all with google scripts without creating external php script?
I am new to google scripts (and don't have big experience in scripting), could you give me some examples, which I could use to implement such a task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am new to google scripts (and don't have big experience in
>   scripting), could you give me some examples

Here are couple of App Scripts reads to get you started:

- Appscript has the [Gmail Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/) which allows scripts to send email and access a user's Gmail account. For more advanced and added features, check the [Advanced Gmail Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail).
- App Script also [supports PHP](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/php).

Since you mentioned about REST calls, checkout [URL Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/) in App Script. This service allows scripts to access other resources on the web by fetching URLs. A script can use the UrlFetch service to issue HTTP and HTTPS requests and receive responses. The UrlFetch service uses Google's network infrastructure for efficiency and scaling purposes.

Each of those guides has a Sample page you can check.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am not sure, that I need external PHP script.
I need only post user login and password and than post one more request to change setting within this login.
Maybe it's possible to do everything with google apps script...

Comment: And Is there a way to run script, when new email is received without using the timer?

Comment: every link i gave you is about App Script.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried yesterday. It's not so complicated as I expected.